# Email Audit API usage

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-email-audit-api

I am using [Email Audit API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/) in a daily basis (setting/deleting monitors).

According to the [Usage Limits and Quotas](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/limits), the limit for monitor creation and deletion is 1000 per day. However, its API usage is not showing anywhere.

In Google API console, there are two APIs seems related (Admin SDK and Audit API), but none of them is showing the usage of the Email Audit API - after I create/delete a monitor via Email Audit API, either the quota of Admin SDK or Audit API remains unchanged.

So I am wondering it is possible to:

- view real-time usage of Email Audit API just like other APIs?
- request an increase of API limit of Email Audit API(setting/deleting monitors specifically)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this to view the usage of Audit API in your [Developers Console](https://pantheon.corp.google.com)

Go to **Audit API** > **Quotas** then click the **Quotas Page**

[image]

As you can see, you can also filter the different option, try to use only Audit API in service part to view the usage of this API. For my example picture, I didn't use the Audit API so the message here is **None of your quotas currently have usage**